# Computation of Laplace operator of Einstein tensor

Tags: differential-geometry, tensors, general-relativity

I'm new to Relativity and I'm trying to understand this computation:
$$ (\nabla^\mu G)_{\mu\nu}=0  $$
where $G=Ric-\frac{1}{2}\mathcal{R}g $  is the Einstein tensor, and $\nabla^\mu=\nabla_{\partial^\mu} $, where $\partial^\mu=g^{\mu\nu}\partial_\nu $ (don't know if it's standard notation).

I use linearity of $\nabla$ and troubles start on the second term, when I try to apply Leibniz rule.
I would write

$$ (\nabla^\mu G)_{\mu\nu} = (\partial^\mu\mathcal{R})g_{\mu\nu} + \mathcal{R}(\nabla^\mu g)_{\mu\nu} $$

but my notes apparently use that
$$ \mathcal{R}(\nabla^\mu g)_{\mu\nu} = 0 $$
cause they omit it. Is it so? Can anyone explain why?

PS: I might write bull***t, as I'm really a newbie in the field.

Comment: Here is what I've tried: $ (\nabla^\mu g)_{\mu\nu}=\partial^\mu(g_{\mu\nu})=g^{\mu\alpha}\partial_\alpha g_{\mu\nu} $, but I don't see why it should be zero.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\nabla^\mu g_{\mu\nu}\neq \partial^\mu g_{\mu\nu}$, but it is true that $\nabla^\mu g_{\mu\nu}=0$ because $\nabla^\mu g_{\mu\nu} = g^{\alpha\mu}\nabla_\alpha g_{\mu\nu}$ and $\nabla_\alpha g_{\mu\nu}=0$ since in general relativity you usually work with the [Levi-Civita connection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levi-Civita_connection), which is [metric-compatible](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metric_connection). I.e., $\nabla g=0$.

Edit: after discussion in the comments

People like to use the notation $\nabla^\alpha g_{\mu\nu}$ for what should be written as $(\nabla g)^\alpha{}_{\mu\nu}$.
Of course, if $\nabla^\alpha g_{\mu\nu}$ were meant to represent $\nabla^\alpha(g_{\mu\nu})$, then it would indeed be equal to $\partial^\alpha g_{\mu\nu}$, since every $g_{\mu\nu}$ is just a scalar function.

Comment: Thanks! So could you also confirm that you can NOT say "$ (\nabla^\alpha g) _{\mu\nu}=\nabla^\alpha( g_{\mu\nu}) $"?

Comment: Also, just to be clear, when you write $\nabla^\alpha g _{\mu\nu}$ you mean $(\nabla^\alpha g) _{\mu\nu}$ right?

Comment: By $\nabla^\alpha g_{\mu\nu}$ I mean the components of the $(1,2)$-tensor field associated to the $(0,3)$-tensor field $\nabla g$ by the isomorphism given by the metric. To be completely precise one could write it as $(\nabla g)^\alpha{}_{\mu\nu}$.

Comment: But yes, I can see how $(\nabla^\alpha g)_{\mu\nu}$ is better notation than $\nabla^\alpha g_{\mu\nu}$, but you should be aware that often people write it as $\nabla^\alpha g_{\mu\nu}$, as I did in the answer. Of course with this we don't mean $\nabla^\alpha(g_{\mu\nu})$, since this would be the covariant derivative of $n^2$ scalar functions, which would equal $\partial^\alpha(g_{\mu\nu})$.

Comment: I hope I got it. Using these symbols with little idea of where they come from is a bit of a nightmare.

Comment: You got it! I hope it goes well.